# Teradata Fastload LDAP authentication issue

Tags: authentication, teradata

I am very new to Teradata. Hopefully, I am asking write question in the forum. :)

I have written fastload script that works absolutely fine on the local machine but fails to authenticate on the environment that requires LDAP for auth.

The main environments uses LDAP authentication. I have used "logmech ldap" in my script but it still doesn't work. Please see below the script I am trying to run:

Error Message: Invalid username password.

Please help me understand what additional commands/info is needed to run this script using LDAP authentication.

The following is the script:

```
logmech ldap;

LOGON server/dbc,"dbc";  
DATABASE DemoDB;

CREATE TABLE SALES3
,FALLBACK
,NO BEFORE JOURNAL
,NO AFTER JOURNAL
(
   ID     VARCHAR(50) TITLE 'ID' NULL
   , BatchId BIGINT TITLE 'BatchId' NULL
   ,CREATED     DATE TITLE 'Created On' NULL
    ,COL0     VARCHAR(50) TITLE 'COL0' NULL
    ,COL1     VARCHAR(50) TITLE 'COL1' NULL
    ,COL2     VARCHAR(50) TITLE 'COL2' NULL
    ,COL3     VARCHAR(50) TITLE 'COL3' NULL
    ,COL4     VARCHAR(50) TITLE 'COL4' NULL
    ,COL5     VARCHAR(50) TITLE 'COL5' NULL
    ,COL6     VARCHAR(50) TITLE 'COL6' NULL
    ,COL7     VARCHAR(50) TITLE 'COL7' NULL
    ,COL8     VARCHAR(50) TITLE 'COL8' NULL
    ,COL9     VARCHAR(50) TITLE 'COL9' NULL
);

BEGIN LOADING DemoDB.SALES3  
ERRORFILES SALES3_ET, SALES3_UV  
CHECKPOINT 100000;  
SET RECORD VARTEXT '≡';

      DEFINE
         "COL0" (VARCHAR(50)),
         "COL1" (VARCHAR(50)),
         "COL2" (VARCHAR(50)),
         "COL3" (VARCHAR(50)),
         "COL4" (VARCHAR(50)),
         "COL5" (VARCHAR(50)),
         "COL6" (VARCHAR(50)),
         "COL7" (VARCHAR(50)),
         "COL8" (VARCHAR(50)),
         "COL9" (VARCHAR(50)),
         "ID" (VARCHAR(50)),
         FILE = 'D:\test.csv';
          INSERT INTO DemoDB.SALES3 (
            BatchId,
            "COL0",
            "COL1",
            "COL2",
            "COL3",
            "COL4",
            "COL5",
            "COL6",
            "COL7",
            "COL8",
            "COL9",
            "ID"
          )
        VALUES (
            10049,    
         :"COL0",
        :"COL1",
        :"COL2",
        :"COL3",
        :"COL4",
        :"COL5",
        :"COL6",
        :"COL7",
        :"COL8",
        :"COL9",
        :"ID"        
      );

   END LOADING;  
LOGOFF;
```

The following is the BTEQ Script:

```
.logmech ldap;
.LOGON server/dbc,"dbc";
SELECT 1 FROM dbc.TablesV WHERE databasename='DemoDB' AND TableName='dwlogSALES3';
.IF activitycount =0 THEN .GOTO FirstLabel
DROP TABLE DemoDB.dwlogSALES3;
.Label FirstLabel
  SELECT 1 FROM dbc.TablesV WHERE databasename='DemoDB' AND TableName='SALES3_UV';
.IF activitycount =0 THEN .GOTO SecondLabel
DROP TABLE DemoDB.SALES3_UV;
.Label SecondLabel
 SELECT 1 FROM dbc.TablesV WHERE databasename='DemoDB' AND TableName='SALES3_ET';
.IF activitycount =0 THEN .GOTO ThirdLabel
DROP TABLE DemoDB.SALES3_ET;
.Label ThirdLabel
  SELECT 1 FROM dbc.TablesV WHERE databasename='DemoDB' AND TableName='SALES3_WK';
.IF activitycount =0 THEN .GOTO FourthLabel
DROP TABLE DemoDB.SALES3_WK;
.Label FourthLabel
SELECT 1 FROM dbc.TablesV WHERE databasename='DemoDB' AND TableName='sales3';
.IF activitycount =0 THEN .GOTO FifthLabel
DROP TABLE DemoDB.sales3;
.Label FifthLabel
 .LOGOFF;
```

Comment: Did you follow the directions found here: http://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/Database_Management/B035-1100-160K/jpo1472240741479.html#?

Comment: Yes I have used logmech with logon as suggested here: http://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/Database_Management%2FB035-1100-160K%2Fmwy1472240753585.html%23wwID0EW6PQ

Comment: Seems silly to ask, but have you verified your failed logon in DBC.LogOnOffV shows the mechanism used was LDAP and the event is "Logon Failed"? Have you tested a BTEQ script with the same credentials and logon mechanism? (Trying to throw some ideas around here.)

Comment: Thanks for responding @Rob. I have used BTEQ script as well and it works fine with LDAP. I will not edit my post to show the code in bteq script.